# Тайловый редактор карт. Теоретические вопросы.

Tags: разработка-игр

Здравствуйте, обьясните пожалуйста теорию редактора тайловых карт. Каким форматом лучше всего хранить карты, как реализовать передвижение камеры по карте, и прочую теорию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вряд ли здесь кто-то возьмётся подробно расписывать этот вопрос. В интернете масса статей по этой теме, нужно лишь поискать. Например, [вот эта](http://www.dionaholding.ru/news/articles/tbg_flash). В ней описывается создание тайловой игры с нуля. В качестве технологии выбран Flash, но, думаю, вам это не помешает. Попробуйте почитать главы 1, 2, 13 и 14.

Comment: Спасибо, я именно литературу и имел ввиду.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку!)